# How to activate a phpDox enricher?

Tags: php, documentation

PhpDox documentation tool (http://phpdox.de) has a couple of enrichers (http://phpdox.de/documentation.html#enrichers) I have searched but I have not found how to activate or deactivate these enrichers before running the script that generates the documentation

Comment: Looking at http://phpdox.de/getting-started.html you can see that there is some sort of `phpdox.xml.dist` config file so it is 99% probably that you enable an enricher in there...

Comment: Thanks @MonkeyZeus! Here this example file: https://github.com/theseer/phpdox/blob/master/phpdox.xml.dist Please consider put your comment as a response and I could upvote it!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at http://phpdox.de/getting-started.html you can see that there is some sort of `phpdox.xml.dist` config file so it is 99% probable that you enable an enricher in there.